# Percentage symbol in $(shell) in GNU Makefile dependency

Tags: make, gnu-make

I am aware of LatexMk, but can't install that on the machine where I want to run `pdflatex`, so I need to write a Makefile of which `%.pdf` files are targets that depend on `%.tex` and the `*.tex` files that `%.tex` is inputting. For this I wrote the following:

```
%.pdf : %.tex $(shell perl -lne 'print "$$1\n" if /\\input{([\w-]+\.tex)}/' %.tex)
```

Now, I tested the regular expression and it seems to work fine, but the `%.tex` at the end isn't passed correctly, running `make output.pdf` gives me:

```
Can't open %.tex: No such file or directory.
```

How can I pass `%.tex` to the `$(shell)` command?

I'm using GNU make.

Comment: Your code does not look like make syntax. Are you sure about this code?

Comment: @schily it's only the target line, but otherwise, yes.

Comment: This is not `make` syntax at all, but the text before the $ could be a SunPro-make enhancement that was introduced in Spring 1986: an implicit pattern matching rule. Such a rule may not be followed by everything you wrote starting with $ and the command line for the rule is missing.

Comment: @schily `%.pdf` is the target, `%.tex` is the first dependency and `$(shell ...)` should create a further list with dependencies. That's what I learned [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules). I'm using GNU Make 3.81, and all this runs fine *except* that the final `%.tex` doesn't expand. Please provide reference for "This is not `make` syntax at all".

Comment: As mentioned already: this is not understood by `make`. $(shell ) is definitely illegal make syntax. Text like this is not permitted in a pattern matching rule and even a pattern matching rule is a SunPro-make enhancement already. See the POSIX make description for leal `make`syntax: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html

Comment: @schily all right, I've worked with `$(shell...)` in other situations but anyway... How *can* I get this to work?

Comment: $(shell) is non-portable vendor-unique `gmake` syntax not understood by `make`. Given that this is a dynamic `gmake` macro that is evaluated at time of use, it can never occur in a implicit rule definition. You may have luck with a statically assigned macro but this is not granted as it is not part of the documented description for pattern matching rules for the reference implementation for pattern matching rules - which is SunPro-make.

Comment: CamilStaps just specify you're using GNU (presumably) make, so that users like @schily can know how much of a standard is applicable. That said, I think `$( )` is evaluated when the make reads the Makefile, not when the rule is called. You might try something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/16930160/2072269, http://stackoverflow.com/a/10416422/2072269

Comment: @muru done. Thanks for the links, I saw the first one already before and was hoping for a better solution... but probably it isn't possible indeed.

Comment: You are mistaken, $() is evaluated when it is used and not when it is read. It cannot be at the right ride of the colon from a pattern matching rule. BTW: this is why I mentioned that it does not look like valid makefile syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what you're trying to do is better solved by creating a file listing dependencies, which you can then `include` from your Makefile.  This is a common pattern in C and C++ makefiles.

```
SOURCES=foo.tex bar.tex

all: $(SOURCES:.tex=.pdf)

%.dep: %.tex
    perl -lne 'print "$*.pdf: $$1\n" if /\\input{([\w-]+\.tex)}/' <$< >$@

include $(SOURCES:.tex=.dep)
```

Recommended reading: [Generating Prerequisites Automatically](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Prerequisites.html) in the Make manual.

Comment: Tested and confirmed. My target line is now `%.pdf: %.tex %.dep`. Thanks!

Comment: This looks like valid make syntax ;-) but it still triggers a `gmake` problem I reported in 1998 and that is still not fixed. You will get a warning that the .dep file is missing even though there is a rule to make it.

Comment: @Camil The target line should just be `%.pdf: %.tex` - the `%.dep` is implicitly a dependency of the `Makefile`.  And inside each `.dep` file, you'll have `foo.pdf: include1.tex` etc. lines (I made a typo in my answer; now fixed).

Comment: Right, that looks better (and is hereby also confirmed to work). Thanks again!